# How high can the Mavic Mini fly?

Tags: dji, dji-mavic-mini

I was wondering how high the DJI Mavic Mini could fly before the air became too thin. I know that there are restrictions in the app (and probably in the drone/controller itself) but if you were able to override those things, how high would it go (not including battery life)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maximum altitude is 3000m (about 9800 ft.)

*(Note that this is relative to [mean sea level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_level), not the ground.)*

Sources:

- [DJI Mavic Mini "Specs" page](https://www.dji.com/uk/mavic-mini/specs) (under "Max Takeoff Altitude")
- [DJI Mavic Mini "FAQ" page](https://www.dji.com/uk/mavic-mini/faq) (under "Propulsion" > "What is Mavic Mini's maximum service ceiling?")

Comment: Note that you'd likely need all kinds of FAA/regulatory permits before you can go anywhere close to that altitude. IIRC the limit for non-permitted use is like 400 ft AGL

Comment: Unless your launch site is already at altitude? You could be 100ft AGL and 9900ft.